# Rails - best way to display code only in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few pieces of code that I would like to display only in production, for instance, the showing of disqus comments. What is the best way to go about doing that? Currently I have:

```
<% if RAILS_ENV.eql?('production') %>
    disqus code here
<% end %>
```

But I am not sure if that's the best method, or is that it? Seems pretty verbose and I would need this in a few different places in the application.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'd suggest writing a helper method in your `application_helper.rb` file:

```
def render_disqus
    return '' unless Rails.env.production?
    #render disqus stuff here...
end
```

Then, in your view it gets really simple:

```
<%= render_disqus %>
```

Comment: `if not` could be changed to `unless`

Answer (score 52):

The effective check is

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
  disqus code here
<% end %>
```

There is no need to put it as a constant in your environment.rb or an initializer. Just keep your code simple and use Rails.env.production? in your main code base I say.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display something in production, but not on a certain page(s), you can do something like this:

```
<% if !current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'dashboard') %>
  <% if Rails.env.production? %>
    <!-- contant go here -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```